Police parody where perp gets shot then cops yell FREEZE
I'm trying to identify which movie a remembered scene is from. American film, probably made in the 90's or early 2000's, parody in the vein of "The Naked Gun" or "Loaded Weapon". The protagonist(s) are chasing a villain's henchman for information (in vehicles) and temporarily lose him. They round the corner and several police cars have a small house surrounded, with the henchman supposedly inside. 
At some point, the perp walks out the front door and gets riddled with bullets - hundreds of 'em. The house looks like swiss cheese, and so does the perp, and a few seconds after he falls to the ground one of the cops yells "Freeze or we'll shoot!". If I remember right, the perp is later in the hospital with only superficial wounds.
My mind keeps putting Leslie Nielsen as the main protagonist, but that may not be right. I didn't see any mention of the scene in summaries for the "Naked Gun" movies or "Spy Hard".
Can someone identify this parody film for me?
Note: It is not the scene from Night Patrol (1984) where the cop shoots the fleeing prisoner and then yells "Stop or I'll shoot!". It's also not from the "Police Academy" franchise or "Sledge Hammer" series. The scene in "Naked Gun 2" where Frank drives the tank through the house is the exact same situation I'm thinking of, albeit with a different outcome.

One parody franchise with a similar tone to Naked Gun is Police Academy. I've only seen one or two of them though, several years ago and don't recall that specific scene.

Wrongly accused or spy hard maybe. I remember he drove a police tank through the house too.

@Erik Police Academy never went to the fake-reality level of parody where you would see something like a person full of holes who was later ok. It was always more "realistic" in that the things it showed weren't generally impossible in reality.

@GendoIkari you could be right. My memory of the franchise is foggy. I mostly remember slapstick wacky hi-jinks. I don't remember any real details.

@cde - the driving a tank through the house bit sounds familiar, and also made me think of Sledge Hammer (I can just see him saying "Dori, will you quit worrying - I know what I'm doing"), but it wasn't from that either.

@cde - the scene with the tank is from the second "Naked Gun" movie, but that isn't the one I'm thinking of. Very close, but not it.

This is something one of my fave TV shows, Reno 911, might do. Not the correct answer, I know. Just brought back memories. :-)
